# MongoDB best optimisation on embedded documents using index

Tags: mongodb, optimization, indexing

In MondoDB, how can you optimize better a collection with embedded documents using index, if you need to query the embedded document?

For example, in a collection with the following format:

```
{
    name: “Andy”,
    address: {
        city: “London”,
        street: “Sunny St.”
    }
}
```

If we need to query by:

```
db.collection.find( {$and: [ {"address.city ": “London”}, {"address”: “Sunny St."} ] } )
```

Which type of index will be better:

```
1.  db.collection.createIndex({"address":1})

2.  db.collection.createIndex({"address.city ":1}) 
    db.collection.createIndex({"address.street":1})

3.  db.collection.createIndex({"address.city ":1, "address.street":1})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for given query proposal number 3

> db.collection.createIndex({"address.city ":1, "address.street":1})

will do the job as there is logical relation city=> street

if you need to get more precise output how mongo uses index and perform your own test use query.explain("executionStats") to see index usage.

[more here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/)

Comment: Thanks profesor. I would have thought that the first option would also achieve the same. I'll do some tests with "executionStats". Thanks for the link